# my app getting crashed when i use this threads codes

Tags: java, android, multithreading, button, android-studio

My purpose is simple,I want to creat a countdown that count from 10 to 1.I have tried using countdown given by google but I can't make it as a thread,so I use this way to creat the same function but I had a problem with this code.My app getting crashed when I use this threads code.Please help me man.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity { 
TextView textView;
Handler handler = new Handler(){

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        String string = textView.getText().toString();
        int num = Integer.parseInt(string);
        num = num-1;
        string = Integer.toString(num);
        textView.setText(string);
    }

};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() { 
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          for(int i = 10; i>0;i--){
              try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                //handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage());
                handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage());

              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

          } 
        }
    });
    myThread.start();

}



}
```

Comment: here is the link for my Log-cat,   https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipO-kaTwmY54c70Mk0K67h9sAwA77qLYjoTxClh2jxpUj9uJGeBczYkhvU_TkInLsw/photo/AF1QipM0O6Q33D-l0x8We0RWskSk_Tt5iNr5iD84cr8T?key=bWZER2lkTkZoNDNYTjJxLXdsYS1pWFFnMzU1WUZR

Comment: You should paste your actual logcat messages into your post. Not add a link in a comment to a photo of it

Comment: ok brother,after I get 10 reputations

Comment: Brother, you don't need any special rep amount to use the edit button below the tags and copy/paste the logcat output in your post as you did with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem isnt with the thread, its with these lines

```
String string = textView.getText().toString(); 
int num = Integer.parseInt(string);
```

You probably have that textView starting out with some text in the XML("Large Text"). Remove it. "Large Text" isn't a number, so when you call parseInt() on that original string its trying to convert "Large Text" to a number.

Try this code:

```
try {
    String string = textView.getText().toString(); 
    int num = Integer.parseInt(string);  
    textView.setText(String.valueOf(--num)); 
catch(NumberFormatException ignored){

}
```

with a try/catch block

Comment: thank you so much bro,I love you.you solved my problem!.

Comment: Anytime =p. Glad you got it working. Here is a cool little tip i discovered not too long ago.. add this namespace to your layout XML file, xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 

Now if you want to see text inside the preview, instead of setting the actual text value with android:text="Large Text" use tools:text="Large Text". When you build your app it wont actually have a value, but it will show up in the preview.

Comment: ya that's good info! appreciated it .I have tried it and it's works.